# How to compare java class in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my Kotlin project, I use [android-gpuimage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage). 
Basically I want to convert the following from Java:

```
    if (mFilter == null || (filter != null && !mFilter.getClass().equals(filter.getClass()))) {
        mFilter = filter;
        mGPUImage.setFilter(mFilter);
        mFilterAdjuster = new GPUImageFilterTools.FilterAdjuster(mFilter);
    }
```

The auto conversion of Android Studio 3 gives me:

```
    if (mFilter == null || filter != null && mFilter.javaClass != filter.javaClass) {
        mFilter = filter
        mGPUImage.setFilter(mFilter)
        mFilterAdjuster = GPUImageFilterTools.FilterAdjuster(mFilter)
    }
```

The code does not compile with the following error:

```
  is not satisfied: inferred type GPUImageFilter? is not a subtype of Any
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: inside the if, mFilter.javaClass is highlighted as error and does not give any suggestion when hovered

Comment: Show your complete method with all variable declarations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What line is the error on? You're trying to put a nullable type (inferred) into something that is `Any` which is not nullable. You need to add a null check operator `!!` which throws. Or do a safe check with `let` or `if`. So instead off:

```
receiver.method(somethingNullable)
```

do either

```
receiver.method(somethingNullable!!)
```

or

```
somethingNullable?.let {
   receiver.method(it) 
}
```

or

```
if (somethingNullable != null) {
    receiver.method(somethingNullable)
}
```

instead of

Comment: This is my first kotlin project and im kind of confused on the code you provied however your explanation gave me hint, so i tried to  mFilter?.javaClass != filter.javaClass and that works